# How to use VBA in Microsoft project to time scale a custom cost field?

Tags: vba, ms-project

[image]

I am trying to time scale the custom cost fields "labor" and "material" so I can view how these data are distributed over a given time horizon.

```
Sub MSCostOutlay()

    'This macro will copy timescaled variance data into the Baseline9Cost field.
    
    Dim TSVBaselineCost As TimeScaleValue 'Capture the dataset for the Baseline10Cost
    Dim TSVSBaselineCost As TimeScaleValues
    Dim t As Task
    
'    ActiveProject.StatusDate = InputBox("Enter the Status Date.", "Status Date", ActiveProject.StatusDate)
    
  

    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
                Set TSVSBaselineCost = t.TimeScaleData((ActiveProject.StatusDate), ActiveProject.StatusDate, pjTaskTimescaledBaseline9Cost, pjTimescaleMonths, 1)
                For Each TSVBaselineCost In TSVSBaselineCost
                    TSVBaselineCost = t.Cost4
                Next TSVBaselineCost
                t.Baseline9Cost = t.Baseline9Cost + 1
    Next t


End Sub
```

Above is the code I tried to use to store the labor cost in a time scaled array. I tried testing this script on one day worth of data to cut down on processing time. Regardless, I kept getting a run-time error of 1101 with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will time-phase the Cost5 values over the span of each task utilizing the Baseline9Cost field as that field can be time-scaled whereas the numbered Cost fields (e.g. Cost5) cannot.

[image: Task Usage view]

Here's the code:

```
Sub MSCostOutlay()

    Dim tsv As TimeScaleValue
    Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues
    Dim t As Task

    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        t.Baseline9Cost = t.Cost5
        Set tsvs = t.TimeScaleData((t.Start), t.Finish, pjTaskTimescaledBaseline9Cost, pjTimescaleDays, 1)
        For Each tsv In tsvs
            If Application.DateDifference(tsv.StartDate, tsv.EndDate) > 0 Then
                tsv = t.Baseline9Cost / (t.Duration / (60 * 8))
            End If
        Next tsv
    Next t

End Sub
```

Notes:

- When entering timescale data, use days rather than months and skip non-working days.
- Remember that duration is stored in minutes so 1 day = 480 minutes (60 * 8)

Comment: Rachel, thank you for getting back to me! I would ideally like to time scale cost9 but ms project does not offer that as a task usage detail. Perhaps I am missing something. Also, how do I store my custom cost field "labor" data into the baseline9 cost or cost fields?

Comment: Is it possible to use VBA to create a new detail and time scale it? Is it possible to view the custom cost field "Labor" in the task usage view?

Comment: @BP130 Numbered cost fields such as Cost5 cannot be time-scaled. I updated the code to simplify it (using the task Start, Finish, Duration) rather than transferring that data to the Baseline9 fields.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I am getting a run time error 1101 while executing the script at step "tsv = t.Baseline9Cost / (t.Duration / (60 * 8))". Any idea on how I can troubleshoot this error?

Comment: @BP130 I have not been able to replicate that error. Check to see if you are getting the error on the very first loop (use F8 to step through the code) or it the error comes on a particular task in which case see what's different about that one.

Comment: I ran the loop. It fails on the first iteration. All the tasks are the exact same. The error is saying that the argument value is not valid. This is strange to me because the locals window is suggesting that all data types should agree with each other.

Comment: @BP130 Sounds like your Baseline9Cost field is read-only. Here's the [list of fields that can be timescaled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjtasktimescaleddata); some of these are definitely read-only such as ACWP which generates the same error if you try to write to it.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try to test a few of these to see if anything works. In the meantime, is there any other solution to time scaling a custom field that I haven't thought of and that you haven't offered? Solving this problem would be a huge help!

Comment: I am wondering what I should try to edit to turn make my argument valid. It appears that your script did not have an issue with the validity of the arguments. I have had 1101 run time errors occur while looping through tasks that had summary summations. I am going to test if disabling summation does the trick.

Comment: I addressed a comment to both you and John on the thread below. I am not getting an error 6, which is labeled "overflow".

Comment: @BP130 For overflow errors, make sure you are dividing Duration by 480 (not multiplying) and try separating that part out so try `DurHrs = (t.Duration / (60 * 8))` and then do `tsv = t.Baseline9Cost / DurHrs`. As for front-loading cost, use a Flag field on the task and then do something like `If tsk.Flag1 Then... Else... End If` and have two versions of the TimeScaleData code to place the costs accordingly.

Comment: I troubleshot the overflow error thanks to your help! I have two more questions for you or John and then I think I accomplished all I set out to do with this project. Is there any way to use VBA to edit the display name of "Baseline9 Cost" to show "Labor Cost"? Second, how do I use VBA code to ensure that the task summary line items are only summing tasks and not adhering to the logic of the script you and john helped develop?

Comment: I can explain more thoroughly if anything is unclear in my comment. I could also share an image of the script I am executing with you. I made a few modifications to what you and john provided me. I am new to stackoverflow so I am not entirely sure if it's possible to post an image as a comment. Please let me know your thoughts! Both you and John have really helped me out!

Comment: BP130. For your first question, sorry, no can do. You can change the title of the Baseline9Cost field as displayed in a view (e.g. Gnatt Chart or Task Usage view) but you cannot rename basic Project fields. Only extra fields (e.g. Cost1, Text1, etc.) can be renamed. For your second question I don't quite understand what you are saying. I think it would help if you did post your current code but I'm new to StackOverflow also so I don't know how best you can do that. Hopefully Rachel will jump back in as she is a seasoned StackOverflower.

Comment: BP130. As an additional comment, if you want to keep everything in Project then the approach you've selected is probably the best option. However, if you want more flexibility in presenting the data (e.g. showing the spread as "Labor Cost"), I suggest you consider the option of exporting the data to Excel using VBA (no need to use a Baseline field).

Comment: @john-project, how do I change the title of the "Baseline9 Cost" field as displayed in a view (e.g. Gnatt Chart or Task Usage view) ? This sounds like exactly what I need. I want the end-user of this project file to see "labor Cost" and not "Baseline9 Cost" in the task usage view to avoid confusion.

Comment: @john-project, I first used excel VBA to achieve the functionality I am trying to replicate in this MS Project file. However, the end user of this project file is looking for a tool that centralizes all information and analysis. Hence, why I headed down this pathway using vba in the project file itself. I am going to make another post outlining the problem I am now trying to solve. Please check it out if possible. Thank you for all the help thus far!

Comment: BP130. In the Gantt Chart or Task Usage view right click on the column heading for the Baseline9 Cost field. Then click Field Settings. Enter "Labor Cost" in the Title box. I'll look for your new post.

Comment: @BP130 Yes, make a new post for your question about Summary tasks. And no, unfortunately it does not appear that you can change the title/label for the timephased values in the Task Usage view. FYI posting code as text is much preferred to an image of the code. See the SO Help center; [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start.

Comment: @RachelHettinger and John, thanks for all the help. I made a new post further explaining my last two challenges.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you get the error because the code is not correctly identifying non-working days in the timescaled data. For reference, your code runs fine, (as written), for me using Project 2019 on Windows 10. Try the following tweak and see if it runs now.

```
    Dim tsv As TimeScaleValue
    Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues
    Dim t As Task

    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        t.Baseline9Cost = t.Cost5
        t.Baseline9Duration = Application.DateDifference(t.Start, t.Finish)
        Set tsvs = t.TimeScaleData((t.Start), t.Finish, pjTaskTimescaledBaseline9Cost, pjTimescaleDays, 1)
        For Each tsv In tsvs
            If ActiveProject.Calendar.Period(tsv.StartDate, tsv.EndDate).Working Then
                tsv = t.Baseline9Cost / (t.Baseline9Duration / (60 * 8))
            End If
        Next tsv
    Next t

End Sub
```

John

Comment: John, thanks for the recommendation/help. I tried your script and am still getting the run-time error. I am not sure how to proceed. Are there any other tips you might have? FYSA - I am using MS Project Standard 2016.

Comment: BP130, I'd check a few things. First, hover your mouse over the arguments in the failing line of code. That will tell you which values are causing the issue. Then track that down. Second, create a simple file with just a few lines and values in Cost5. Does the code run on that? Third, check your VBA references. There should be 4 references in the basic set: VB for apps, Project Obj lib, OLE automation, and Office Obj Lib. If I could actually see your file for testing that would be great but I don't know how that works on this forum.

Comment: recommendations one and two have been executed. The simple file failed to work too. I am not sure how to conduct recommendation three. I would be open to sharing my small test file.

Comment: BP130, sorry I didn't notice this before but you are using manually scheduled tasking. When I change one of the tasks in my test file to be manually scheduled, I get error 1101. Why? Because entries in the Start and Finish fields of manually scheduled tasks are string type, not date type and that is probably why the code fails. I suggest you convert your file to all auto-scheduled tasks.

Comment: @john-project You found the issue--if the task is manually scheduled, the time-phasing is read-only. I have no idea why that would be. (FYI the task start/finish dates are still dates even when manually scheduled.)

Comment: Rachel, yeah they still appear as dates but they are stored differently in Project's database. Personally I think the addition of manual scheduling for Project was a mistake but of course that's my humble opinion

Comment: @john-project and Rachel, thank you very much for the help! This resolved the issue in my test file with 5 tasks. After proving the script worked in my test file, I tried it on the real file that needs this application. The file I applied the script to has a few thousand lines. An overflow error (i.e., error 6) occurred at step "tsv = t.Baseline9Cost / (t.Duration / (60 * 8))". After some research, it seems like a data type issue. However, I am not sure how to correct it. Do either of you have any recommendations on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Also, how would incorporate a cost that is not prorated in the time scale script you both provided? For example, say a $1000 material purchase is resource loaded onto a task and its set to accrue at the start of the task while labor costs are prorated.